# Crear una función global en Angular

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-2.0, angular4

Me estoy volviendo loco, porque estoy pasando de AngularJS a Angular 5. Yo usaba para ciertas funciones y variables que quería usar en varias páginas $rootScope, pero todo eso ha desaparecido con Angular y por lo visto se usan servicios para hacerlo, pero sinceramente me parece muy complicado y sólo encuentro información en inglés y me está costando... alguien puede hacerme un resumen en español de como puedo hacerlo?

Gracias

Answer (score 3, accepted):

En Angular 5, puede usar servicios para realizar, lo que necesitas es crear un servicio con:

```
ng g service nombre-del-servicio
```

luego se te generara un "ts" de la siguiente manera:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable()

export class SomeService {

  constructor() { }

}
```

en este "ts" puedes crear metodos, donde vas a almacenar Arreglos, cadenas, numero , entre otro, por ejemplo, declarare un método para almacenar un estatus de boleano.

```
status:boolean = false;
constructor() { }

/* funcion para almacenar un boleano*/

saveStatus(value){
 this.status = value;
}

/* funcion para obtener un status almacenado*/

getStatus(){
 return this.status;
}
```

Este servicio lo puede llamar en cualquier componente solo importando el servicio como :

```
import { SomeService } 'path-del-servicio';
```

> NOTA: Necesitas que el servicio este registrado en el "app.module.ts" del arreglo de "providers".

Comment: Hola @GustavoSL justo estaba haciendo algo como en tu ejemplo, solo que me quedé varada, al acceder a la funciones ¿cómo puedo utilizar ambas funciones? Quiero decir, voy al ts donde lo necesito y luego primero tendría que almacenar el status¿cierto? como true/false Luego obtener el status ¿estoy en lo correcto?